# How can i add image by mediapipe.js or tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

[image]

how can i add image by mediapipe.js or tensorflow.js like previous photo
Or how can I add a picture to  the body or the human face
For example, I want to add glasses and accessories, change clothes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this question goes against guidelines because of how vague it is, but
I'll refer you to some examples.

[Simple Face Filter](https://github.com/iamhimanshu0/face-filter)

[Advanced Example](https://github.com/njpietrow/Filter.io)